# How can I can convert my JS Object to FormData?

Tags: javascript, form-data

How can I define object in object
in FormData?

for example:

```
var item = {
   description: 'kavan ahmadi',
   price : '0.00',
   item1:{ firtname:'k1', file:'file'},
   count:'1'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To define the object in form data, you need to append each object property and value into [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData#example).

Just append the **key and its value** into **formData**.

Here is the ES6 approach:

```
function getFormData(object) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
      if (typeof object[key] !== 'object') formData.append(key, object[key])
      else formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(object[key]))
    })
    return formData;
}
```

Just pass your object into the **getFormData** function, and it will do the rest.

Check with your code example: https://jsbin.com/lurocexoxi/edit?js,console,output

Comment: You could `JSON.stringify()` every value (not just objects). They're all converted to strings anyways in your network request

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass non-primitive values (eg objects, arrays) as values to `formData.append`. Your choices, then, are to use dot-syntax in your keys:

```js
formData.append('item1.firstName', 'Jimminey');
formData.append('item1.lastName', 'Cricket');
```

Or stringify the object;

```js
formData.append('item1', '{ "firstName": "Jimminey", "lastName": "Cricket" }');
```

Here's an example, with non-primitive values converted to JSON strings:

```js
let formData = new FormData();

// Loop through the object
for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(item)) {
  // append each item to the formData (converted to JSON strings)
  formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(val));
}
```

If you want to send complex data in a network request, you're better off sending it as `application/json` (JSON document), instead of `multipart/form-data` (FormData)